# Change whole blender scene into a cartoon look

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, shaders, color

So, I have a scene full of meshes (around 70 or so) each with own textures (no normal maps etc tho).

I am wondering if there is a way how to change the whole global scene into something more **cartoony**. Like setting global shadows differently?

I saw a tutorial of changing the surface of the material into Toon BSDF, but doing that for each model? And wouldn´t that ruin the textures?

Isn´t there something like when you can change in Photoshop the saturation, colour ramp and other settings of a picture?

Comment: Try freestyle. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple toon shader mixed with a texture. Use multiply for the mix to transfer the darkness values only - keeps the base (un-shaded) texture intact. I multiplied it twice to magnify the effect.

[image: ToonShader]